# ‎Testing nativescript build on iOS

Tags: nativescript, sidekick

We have built a NativeScript application for iOS using nativescript sidekick cloud build (We don't have a mac, this was done on Linux)
Build was successfull.
How do we send it to testflight so we can run it on iPad?

Answer (score 0):

You should build in release and for a device - for that, you will need a proper provisioning profile. From there publish the app (via Sidekick, or `tns publish` or via XCode as you prefer) and you will see the IPA in https://appstoreconnect.apple.com.

From that point, you could test the release in Test Flight as any other uploaded iOS app.

Comment: So you mean I need a distribution provisioning profile, not a development one and then simply publish, as if I send it to apple for review and then it will be available for testflight?